# Is there a quick way to place a frame on multiple photos?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photo-editing, illustration, design-principles

I was wondering if there is a quick way or a tip to place a banner template on multiple photos without having to make it invidually as I'm working in a company supplying me with pictures and i need to place a fixed frame design on them.

Comment: Can I ask, why are you are using illustrator for this?

Comment: Google Photoshop actions.

Comment: Photoshop wasn't working on my laptop, however i changed it last night, can you please tell me how to do that on Photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Photoshop you can do that quickly, using Actions. In the link below you can see how to do it. But basically you open the actions panel, click "record" and you do the whole process for what you want, in this case you create the frame. Then you just need to save it, and apply it to multiple images, and it does it by itself for all the images you selected.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html